# How to validate user inputs in the UI boundary in a 3 tier model?

Tags: java, javafx-8, object-oriented-analysis, 3-tier

The first class is the fxController which is my UIBoundary.
The second class is the controller class.
The third class is an entity class.

```js
package fxcontroller;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.regex.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import entity.*;
import controller.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class RegistrationFXMLController implements Initializable {

 //Volunteer
 @FXML
 private TextField vnric;
 @FXML
 private TextField vname;
 @FXML
 private TextField vaddress;
 @FXML
 private TextField vphone;
 @FXML
 private TextField vemail;
 @FXML
 private TextField vusername;
 @FXML
 private TextField vpassword;
 @FXML
 private TextField vcpassword;
 @FXML
 private Button btnvcancel;
 @FXML
 private Button btnvsignup;
 @FXML 
 private ListView<String> vdate;
 @FXML
 private ListView<String> vtime;
 @FXML
 private Tab vrole;

 //Donor
 @FXML
 private TextField dnric;
 @FXML
 private TextField dname;
 @FXML
 private TextField daddress;
 @FXML
 private TextField dphone;
 @FXML
 private TextField demail;
 @FXML
 private TextField dusername;
 @FXML
 private TextField dpassword;
 @FXML
 private TextField dcpassword;
 @FXML
 private Button btndcancel;
 @FXML
 private Button btndsignup; 
 @FXML
 private Tab drole;

 //Handicap
 @FXML
 private TextField hid;
 @FXML
 private TextField hnric;
 @FXML
 private TextField hname;
 @FXML
 private TextField haddress;
 @FXML
 private TextField hphone;
 @FXML
 private TextField hemail;
 @FXML
 private TextField husername;
 @FXML
 private TextField hpassword;
 @FXML
 private TextField hcpassword;
 @FXML
 private Button btnhcancel;
 @FXML
 private Button btnhsignup; 
 @FXML
 private TextField hspecialneed;
 @FXML
 private Tab hrole;

 @FXML
 private void vCancelActionbtn(ActionEvent event){
  System.out.println("Cancel"); //link to log in interface
 }

 @FXML
 private void vSignupActionbtn(ActionEvent event){
  MemberController m = new MemberController();
  m.processRegisterInformationV(vnric.getText(), vname.getText(), vaddress.getText(), vphone.getText(), vemail.getText(), vusername.getText(), vpassword.getText(), (vdate.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()).toString(), (vtime.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()).toString());
  buttonClicked();
 }
 
 @FXML
 private void buttonClicked() {
  String message = "";
  ObservableList<String> days;
  days = vdate.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
  
  for(String m: days){
   message += m + "\n";
  }
  System.out.println(message);
 }

 @FXML
 private void dCancelActionbtn(ActionEvent event){
  System.out.println("Cancel");
 }
 
 @FXML
 private void dSignupActionbtn(ActionEvent event){
  
        MemberController m = new MemberController();
        
//i have tried validating but it does not seems to work
        if(validateNric() == true){
            m.processRegisterInformationD(dnric.getText(),dname.getText(),daddress.getText(),dphone.getText(),demail.getText(),dusername.getText(),dpassword.getText());
        }
        else if(validateName()== true){
            m.processRegisterInformationD(dnric.getText(),dname.getText(),daddress.getText(),dphone.getText(),demail.getText(),dusername.getText(),dpassword.getText());
        }
        else{
           Member d = new Donor();
        d.setNric(dnric.getText().toUpperCase());
        d.setName(dname.getText());
        d.setAddress(daddress.getText());
        d.setHandphone(dphone.getText());
        d.setEmail(demail.getText());
        d.setUsername(dusername.getText());
        try {
    d.setPassword(AeSimpleSHA1.SHA1(dpassword.getText()));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
        } 
  
 }
 
    @FXML
 private void hCancelActionbtn(ActionEvent event){
  System.out.println("Cancel");
 }

 @FXML
 private void hSignupActionbtn(ActionEvent event){
  System.out.println("Congrats, you are now a registered handicap!");
  MemberController m = new MemberController();
  m.processRegisterInformationH(hid.getText(), hnric.getText(), hname.getText(), haddress.getText(), hphone.getText(), hemail.getText(), hspecialneed.getText(), husername.getText(), hpassword.getText());
 }

    //Adding items to ComboBox
 ObservableList<String> listviewlist1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
   "Morning (9.30-11.30am)", "Afternoon(1.30-3.30pm)", "Evening(5.30-7.30pm)");
 
 ObservableList<String> listviewlist2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
   "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
 
 @Override
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
  vtime.setItems(listviewlist1);
  vtime.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
  
     vdate.setItems(listviewlist2);
     vdate.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);    
 }
 
 //Validation for Donor
      private boolean validateNric() {
     boolean result = false;
  int noOfCharacter = 9; 
  String dNric = dnric.getText();
  System.out.println("**************" + dnric.getText());
  Pattern validNricPattern = Pattern.compile("^(S|T|F|G)\\d{7}[A-Z]$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = validNricPattern.matcher(dNric); 
  
  if(dnric.getText().length() == 0){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NRIC/FIN cannot be blank!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  else if(dnric.getText().length() < noOfCharacter || dnric.getText().length() > noOfCharacter){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NRIC/FIN must be 9 characters!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  /*else if(!dnric.getText().substring(0, 9).matches("^(S|T|F|G)\\d{7}[A-Z]$")){
   System.out.println(dnric.getText());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NRIC/FIN must be in S1234567A format!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  else if(!matcher.matches()){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NRIC/FIN must be in S1234567A format!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  } */
  else {
   result = true;
  }
  return result;
 }
  
 private boolean validateName() {
  boolean result = false;
  String dName = dname.getText();
  System.out.println("**************" + dname.getText());
  Pattern validNamePattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z\\s]{1,30}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = validNamePattern.matcher(dName);
  if(dname.getText().trim().equals("")){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NRIC/FIN cannot be blank!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  else if(!dname.getText().substring(0, 29).matches("[A-Za-z\\s]{1,30}")){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in name!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  else if(!matcher.matches()){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in name!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  else {
   result = true;
  }
  return result; 
 }
}
```

```js
package controller;

import entity.*;

public class MemberController {
 
 public void processRegisterInformationV(String nric, String name, String address, String handphone, String email, String username,
   String password, String dateAvail, String timeAvail){
  
  Volunteer v = new Volunteer();
  v.processRegisterInformationV(nric, name, address, handphone, email, username, password, dateAvail, timeAvail);
 }
 
 public void  processRegisterInformationD(String nric, String name, String address, String handphone, String email, String username,
   String password){
   
   Donor d = new Donor();
   d.processRegisterInformationD(nric, name, address, handphone, email, username, password);
 }
 
 public void processRegisterInformationH(String handicapcardId, String nric, String name, String address, String handphone, String email,  String specialNeeds, String username,
   String password){
  Handicap h = new Handicap();
  h.processRegisterInformationH( handicapcardId, nric, name, address, handphone, email, specialNeeds, username, password);
 }
}
```

```js
package entity;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import controller.SQLController;

public class Donor extends Member{
 
 private String donatedate;
 private String donatetime;

 public Donor(int id, String nric, String name, String address, String handphone, String email, String username,
   String password,String role, String donatedate, String donatetime) {
  super(id, nric, name, address, handphone, email, username, password, role);
  this.donatedate = donatedate;
  this.donatetime = donatetime;
 }
 
 public Donor(String nric, String name, String address, String handphone, String email, String username,
   String password) {
  super(nric, name, address, handphone, email, username, password);
 }

 public Donor(){
 }

 public String getDonatedate() {
  return donatedate;
 }
 
 public void setDonatedate(String donatedate) {
  this.donatedate = donatedate;
 }
 
 public String getDonatetime() {
  return donatetime;
 }
 
 public void setDonatetime(String donatetime) {
  this.donatetime = donatetime;
 }
 
 //I want to validate these values here
 public void processRegisterInformationD(String nric, String name, String address, String handphone, String email, String username,
   String password){
  boolean success = false; 
     SQLController db = new SQLController();
     db.getConnection();
  String dbQuery = "INSERT INTO Member(nric, name, address, handphone, email, username, password, role) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  PreparedStatement pstmt = db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);
    
     try{
      pstmt.setString(1, nric);
      pstmt.setString(2, name);
      pstmt.setString(3, address);
      pstmt.setString(4, handphone);
      pstmt.setString(5, email);
      pstmt.setString(6, username);
      pstmt.setString(7, password);
      pstmt.setString(8, "Donor");
      
      if(pstmt.executeUpdate()==1)
       success = true;
      
      pstmt.close();
      }
     catch(SQLException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     
     System.out.println("Donor is already created.");
     db.terminate();
  System.out.println(success);
 }
}
```

Comment: Side note: if you GUI accesses the DB directly and not via some kind of middleware/ remote service, you have a 2-tier application, not a 3-tier application. If the application should support multiple concurrent users, usually a 3-tier application is recommended (not sure if this is the case here).

Comment: Also have a look at try-with-resources (closing your statements and connections correctly) and maybe JPA.